# Get object from action

Tags: c#

I have a class that takes a Action on its constructor. I want the class field _options value to become the value of that action.

I tried to use:

```
_options = options;
```

But this does not compile. The full code is:

```
public class PortableObjectTemplate {

  private PortableObjectTemplateOptions _options { get; set; }

  public PortableObjectTemplate(Action<PortableObjectTemplateOptions> options) {
    _options = options;
  }
}
```

I am trying to be able to use this class as:

```
PortableObjectTemplate pot = new PortableObjectTemplate(x => {
  x.SearchPath = "/";
  x.BlackList = "*.cs";
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What is `action`?

Comment: an `Action` is void, it can't return a value. You should use a `Func`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Sorry, I updated my code. I tried _options = options

Comment: Without knowing the delegates signature and/or the exact compiler-error it´s impossible to guess what your problem is.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I updated my code to show one way of I am trying to initialize the options values of the class through and action.

Comment: Your delegate doesn´t return anything, you´re  just *modifying* the passed instance `x`. However we don´t know where that instance is created. Show what `PortableObjectTemplateOptions ` is. From what you´ve edited your question into it seems you don´t need a delegate at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment an `Action` is a delegate returning nothing at all (or `void`). When you want your delegate to return anything you should use a [`Func<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx) instead and *execute* it:

```
public PortableObjectTemplate(Func<PortableObjectTemplateOptions> options) {
    _options = options();
}
```

Of course you should check if `options` isn´t `null` before executing it (C#6 upwards):

```
_options = options?.Invoke();
```

or alternativly:

```
options = options == null ? default(PortableObjectTemplate) : options();
```

Comment: `options?.Invoke()`.

Comment: Note to self: When you know the answer, don't write it in the comments. :-). +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Create a new instance and pass it to Invoke, which will set all the properties.

```
public PortableObjectTemplate(Action<PortableObjectTemplateOptions> options) {

     var newOptions = new PortableObjectTemplateOptions();
    _options = options.Invoke(newOptions);
```

OR

```
     options.Invoke(_options);
  }
```